# Trying to get a windows forms button to show the next 3 numbers in a text file

Tags: c#, winforms

As question indicates this is what I am trying to do can anyone see how been fiddling with it for a while. Currently it only shows the first 3 numbers in the text file, when I press the nextButton I want it to go to the next 3 but it does not seem to be working..

```
namespace GPSProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int count;
        internal dataPoints myDataPoints;
        public Form1()
        {
            myDataPoints = new dataPoints();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                Button b = (Button)sender;
                if (b.Name.Equals("buttonNext"))
                {

                    count++;
                    if (count == (myDataPoints.Count))
                        count = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    count--;
                    if (count < 0)
                        count = myDataPoints.Count - 1;
                }
                dataPoint a = myDataPoints.getItem(count);
                textBoxLatitude.Text = a.CurLatitude;
                textBoxLongtitude.Text = a.CurLongtitude;
                textBoxElevation.Text = a.CurElevation;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my forms window and below is my dataPoints

```
namespace GPSProject
{
    class dataPoints
    {
        public int Count { get { return Points.Count; } }
        List<dataPoint> Points;
        //string p;

        public dataPoints(/*string path*/)
        {
            Points = new List<dataPoint>();
           // p = path;
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(/*p*/"C:/Test.txt");
            string input;
            while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] bits = input.Split(',');
                dataPoint a = new dataPoint(bits[0], bits[1], bits[2]);
                Points.Add(a);                
            }

            tr.Close();
        }          



        internal dataPoint getItem(int p)
        {
            if (p < Points.Count)
            {
                return Points[p];
            }
            else

                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `3 bits of data`? A single char is at least 8 bits.

Comment: Sorry I mean three numbers, so if 1,2,3,4,5,6 is stored in the text file it will show 1,2,3 and then after you press next will show 4,5,6 - amended question

Comment: is `1,2,3,4,5,6`  in a single line? Does every line contain three numbers?

Comment: It is in a single line separated by commas.

Comment: Does the file have more than one line, or are all your lat/long/alt points on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update your `while` loop to take your data items 3 at a time, something like this:

```
while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] bits = input.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length / 3; i++)
    {
        dataPoint a = new dataPoint(bits[3*i], bits[3*i+1], bits[3*i+2]);
        Points.Add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1744093 - I tested the inside of the while loop in LinqPad and it worked for me. Ar you getting an error?

Comment: the while looop works, but the button does not, i imagine the error is not in the while loop

Comment: If the `buttonNext_Click` method is the `Click` event handler for more than one button (looks like it is), you don't need to compare the button names - just do `if (sender == buttonNext)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
//string input = File.ReadAllText(/*p*/"C:/Test.txt");

List<List<string>> all = input.Split(',')
                        .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.i / 3)
                        .Select(g => g.Select(x=>x.s).ToList())
                        .ToList();

foreach(var bits in all)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", bits[0], bits[1], bits[2]);
    //dataPoint a = new dataPoint(bits[0], bits[1], bits[2]);
    //Points.Add(a); 
}
```

This would give an output

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```